# How to share memory between two child processes belonging to the same parent

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, mmap

I've two child processes (both having same parent) launched with `exec()` system call and i want these two processes to map to the same file for IPC through `mmap()`. The problem i'm having is that one process writes the data (it's own pid) using the pointer returned by `mmap()` but the other process isn't able to read that data. Also i want the second child process to use that pid to know the state of first child process. Any help would be much appreciated as i'm fairly new to this.

*The Parent Process:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
pid_t process, f_child, s_child;
int status;
sem_t synch; 
sem_init(&synch, 1, 0);
process = fork();
if(process<0)
{
perror("Fork Failed");
exit(1);
}
if(process>)
{
//Parent!!
sem_post(&synch); // signaling to child
f_child = wait(&status);
s_child = fork();
if(s_child==0)
{
//Second Child Process!!
execlp("./secondChild", "./secondChild", NULL);
}
}
else
{
//First Child Process!!
sem_wait(&synch);
execlp("./firstChild","./firstChild", NULL);
}
 return 0;
}
```

*First Child Process:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int fd = shm_open("./myFile", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
int *sharedMem = mmap(0, 256, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd, 0);


*sharedMem = getpid();
printf("Child Process 1 wrote message : %d", *sharedMem);
exit(10);
return 0;
}
```

*Second Child Process:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int fd = shm_open("./myFile", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
int *sharedMem = mmap(0, 256, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd, 0);


printf("Child Process 2 readmessage : %d", *sharedMem);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you start by adding some error checking to your "child" processes. Do their `shm_open` call really succeed? How about the `mmap` calls?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've applied error checks on both `shm_open()` and `mmap()` calls. It still doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

`MAP_ANONYMOUS` requests anonymous memory, that is memory that is not independent of any file and the fd argument to mmap is ignored. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you man sem_init on linux ( at least on mine ) it says that the sem_t has to be in a shared memory location; the stack of the parent process is not a shared memory area.   The manual is a bit ambiguous in this regard, as it goes on to say that a forked child inherits these mappings, but I am pretty sure that it means that a forked child inherits shared mappings.